# How to find the rotation angle of google map

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am developing an application which uses the google map, and I am stuck in some functionality.

How to find the value of the rotation angle of google map if user rotated the map in any direction?

Comment: You can see [CLLocationDirection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationdirection?language=objc)

Comment: @Cœur, Ok, thank you!

Comment: What are you using for google maps? I assume that you don't use MKMapView, because that's apple maps.

Comment: try this property : GMSMapView.camera.bearing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GMSMapViewDelegate**

`Bearing` of the camera, in degrees clockwise from true north.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    print(position.bearing)
}
```