# Get google map currently rotated angle by user in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using google map in the application. When I do not rotate map everything works fine. But when I rotate map I am getting problem as shown in image. To solve that I need to get the google map currently rotated angle by the user. I need to get this so that I can place the marker back on the map at the same angle. Currently my map angle after rotation and my overlay seems to be different after placing plan image on map even when I am getting correct top left & bottom right corner coordinates.
My code

```
let topCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: topLattitude, longitude: topLongitude)//top
let bottomCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: bottomLattitude, longitude: bottomLongitude)//bottom
overlayBounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: topCoordinate, coordinate:
bottomCoordinate)

let overlay = GMSGroundOverlay(bounds: overlayBounds, icon: planImage)
    overlay.map = mapView
```

[image: Image showing map is rotated & overlay is in default angle & they both are different in in this case. If I do not rotate map everything works fine.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50855034/5461400

Comment: Thank you. This solution is working fine as of now.

Comment: @HarshalValanda I have got the angle with this method but when I am using that angle while placing back on a map using GMSGroundOverlay image is getting disturbed. I have added overlay.bearing = rotationAngle

Answer (score 0):

```
GMSMapViewDelegate
```

Bearing of the camera, in degrees clockwise from true north.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
print(position.bearing)
```

}

Comment: I have got the angle with this method but when I am using that angle while placing back on a map using GMSGroundOverlay image is getting disturbed. I have added overlay.bearing = rotationAngle

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by changing the overlay method as

```
let zoomLevel = (object["image_zoom_level"] as? NSString)?.doubleValue
let overlay = GMSGroundOverlay(position: centreCoordinate, icon: planImage, zoomLevel: CGFloat(zoomLevel!))
overlay.map = mapView
if let angle = (object["rotation_angle"] as? NSString)?.doubleValue{
     overlay.bearing = angle
}
```

Instead of using Overlay bounds I have just used center coordinate and placed overlay image using image zoom level and rotation angle. By this, my image is placing in proper angle and at a proper place. This works fine if the Image size is correct as you want place and the center point is accurate and precise.